# Calcelar Flujo en Bot de Whatsapp

Tags: javascript, nodejs, npm, whatsapp, bot

lamento las molestias de antemano, estoy intentando crear un pequeño bot, aprendiendo o intentando aprender un poco y me encuentro en un pequeño problema.

es un bot super simple, que al decir cualquier palabra, el comienza un flujo, al escribir 1, deberia de enviar un mensaje y terminar el flujo, entiendo que tiene que chequear de que numero telefonico lo esta haciendo y apagar el flujo para ese numero, lo he intentado, he leido, pero realmente no lo he logrado, estoy seguro que es algo facil, pero sin experiencia complicado.

Adjunto el codigo, alguien quizas pueda ayudarme, feliz tarde nuevamente

Estoy usando **Bailys** de [Bot Whatsapp](https://bot-whatsapp.netlify.app/docs/)

```
const { createBot, createProvider, createFlow, addKeyword, EVENTS } = require('@bot-whatsapp/bot')
const QRPortalWeb = require('@bot-whatsapp/portal')
const BaileysProvider = require('@bot-whatsapp/provider/baileys')
const MockAdapter = require('@bot-whatsapp/database/mock')


function user(ctx) {
 
    return ctx.from;
  }
  
  const welcome = addKeyword(EVENTS.WELCOME).addAnswer(['Bienvenido'])
      .addAnswer([
          'Escribe en el *chat* la opción que deseas.',
          '',
          '1️⃣ Asistente'
      ], { capture: true },
      async (ctx, { endFlow }) => {
          if (user && ctx.body.includes == '1') {
              console.log(user);
              return endFlow({ body: 'Pronto te atenderemos' }, user);
          }
      });

const main = async () => {
    const adapterDB = new MockAdapter()
    const adapterFlow = createFlow([welcome])
    const adapterProvider = createProvider(BaileysProvider)

    createBot({
        flow: adapterFlow,
        provider: adapterProvider,
        database: adapterDB,
    })

    QRPortalWeb()
}

main()
```